# How to close PopupView and show a notification in the same request?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I experienced the following problem with PopupViews: My application has an error handler set in the UI and this error handler shows some error notification by invoking Notification.show(...) when it receives error event. In a popup view I have a button, which performs some action. When one clicks the button, the popup view is closed (by invoking setPopupVisible(false)) and the action is executed. However, if the action fails to run and throws an exception, I expect the exception to be handled by the UI and the error message is to be shown on the screen. Unfortunately, the handler receives the error event and invokes Notification.show, but no message is shown.

Has someone faced the similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use other notification system and run async JavaScript code.
Also you can wrap any other notification system in 10 minutes (implement Vaadin **AbstractJavaScriptComponent**), for example **noty2** (for use should be included jQuery lib): http://needim.github.io/noty/
and show notif when you action executed like this:

```
        new Notty("WARNING<br>description... (static)", Notty.Type.WARNING).show(UI.getCurrent());
        new Notty("WARNING<br>description... (close in 3000ms)", Notty.Type.WARNING, 3000).show(UI.getCurrent());
        new Notty("WARNING<br>description... (modal)", Notty.Type.WARNING, 0, true).show(UI.getCurrent());
        new Notty("WARNING<br>description... (modal force, close in 3000ms)", Notty.Type.WARNING, 3000, true, true).show(UI.getCurrent());
        new Notty("asd", Notty.Type.ERROR, 5000).show(UI.getCurrent());
```

---

```
        package user_interface.util.ext;

        import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
        import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent;
        import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractOrderedLayout;
        import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.Iterator;

        public class Notty implements Serializable {

            private String message;
            private String type;
            private int closeIn = 0;
            private boolean force = false;
            private boolean modal = false;

            public Notty(String message, Notty.Type type) {
                this.message = message;
                this.type = type.value;
            }

            public Notty(String message, Notty.Type type, int closeIn) {
                this.message = message;
                this.type = type.value;
                this.closeIn = closeIn;
            }

            public Notty(String message, Notty.Type type, int closeIn, boolean modal) {
                this.message = message;
                this.type = type.value;
                this.closeIn = closeIn;
                this.modal = modal;
            }    

            public Notty(String message, Notty.Type type, int closeIn, boolean modal, boolean force) {
                this.message = message;
                this.type = type.value;
                this.closeIn = closeIn;
                this.modal = modal;
                this.force = force;
            }

            public void show(UI ui) {

                AbstractOrderedLayout aol = (AbstractOrderedLayout) ui.getContent();

                NottyMessage nm = null;
                boolean wasAdded = false;
                Iterator itr = aol.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    Object o = itr.next();
                    if (o instanceof NottyMessage) {
                        nm = (NottyMessage) o;
                        wasAdded = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!wasAdded) {
                    nm = new NottyMessage();
                    aol.addComponent(nm);            
                }

                nm.show(message, type, closeIn, force, modal);
            }

            @JavaScript({"NottyMessage.js"})
            private class NottyMessage extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

                public NottyMessage() {
                    setImmediate(true);
                }

                @Override
                protected NottyMessageState getState() {
                    return (NottyMessageState) super.getState();
                }        

                private void show(String mess, String type, int closeIn, boolean force, boolean modal) {
                    callFunction("show", mess, type, closeIn, force, modal);
                }

            }

            public static enum Type {

                ALERT("alert"),
                INFORMATION("information"),
                ERROR("error"),
                WARNING("warning"),
                NOTIFICATION("notification"),
                SUCCESS("success");

                private String value;

                private Type(String val) {
                    this.value = val;
                }
            }

        }
```

**NottyMessageState.java**

```
        package user_interface.util.ext;

        import com.vaadin.shared.ui.JavaScriptComponentState;

        public class NottyMessageState extends JavaScriptComponentState {
            public String xhtml;
            public String type;
        }
```

**NottyMessage.js**

```
        user_interface_util_ext_Notty_NottyMessage = function() {

            var e = this.getElement();

            this.onStateChange = function() {
                // change state callb
            }

            this.show = function(message, messageType, closeInMs, isForce, isModal) {
                var n = noty({
                    text: message,
                    type: messageType,
                    dismissQueue: true,
                    timeout: closeInMs,
                    force: isForce,
                    modal: isModal,
                    maxVisible: 7,
                    layout: "bottomLeft",
                    theme: "defaultTheme"
                });
            }

        }
```

it should look like this:

[image: noty2 jQuery plugin in Vaadin7 UI]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the handler is in a different thread and not in the UI thread. I got the same weird behavoir trying to enable a disabled button which did not worked until i used

```
Button button = new Button("foo")

// ...

getUI().access(new Runnable(){
   public void run() {
     button.setEnabled(true)
   }
})
```